# Mac-Laurin-series for $\psi(\frac{2x+1}{2x})-\psi(\frac{x+1}{2x})$?

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion, digamma-function

Consider $$f(x)=\psi(\frac{2x+1}{2x})-\psi(\frac{x+1}{2x})$$

$\psi(x)$ is the digamma-function. This function occurs in the calculation of the definite integral

$$\int_0^1 \ln(x^n+1)dx=\ln(2)-\frac{f(n)}{2}$$ for $n>0$. Wolfram alpha gives a series expansion of $f(x)$ for $x\rightarrow\infty$ , but not for $x\rightarrow 0$ and I could not even calculate $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f'(x)$$, which should be $1$ due to numerical calculation.

> Does the Mac-Laurin-series for $f(x)$ exist ? If yes, how can I find the series ? And, finally, which convergent radius does it have ?

Comment: with $\psi(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2x})-\psi(1+\frac{1}{2x}) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2x}+n}-\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2x}+n} $ you should get what you need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take a look at the chapter about polygamma functions in [Abramowitz and Stegun](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_260.htm).

The multiplication formula (6.4.8) shows:
$$\begin{align*}
\psi(2x) &= \ln(2) + \frac{1}{2}(\psi(x) + \psi(x+1/2)) \\
\iff \psi(x + 1/2) &= 2\psi(2x) - \ln(4) - \psi(x)
\end{align*}$$

The recurrence formula (6.4.6) shows:
$$\psi(1 + x) = \psi(x) + \frac{1}{x}.$$

Combining both we get the following:
$$\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \psi(1 + 1/(2x)) - \psi(1/2 + 1/(2x)) = \psi(1/(2x)) + 2x - 2\psi(2/(2x)) + \ln(4) + \psi(1/(2x)) \\
&= 2\big\{\psi(1/(2x)) - \psi(1/x)\big\} + 2x + \ln(4)
\end{align*}$$

Now we can plug in the asymptotic formula (6.3.18):
$$\begin{align*}
\psi(1/(2x)) - \psi(1/x) &= -\ln(2x) - x - \sum \limits_{k = 1}^n  \frac{B_{2k}}{2k} 2^{2k} x^{2k} + \ln(x) + x/2 + \sum \limits_{k = 1}^n \frac{B_{2k}}{2k} x^{2k} + O(x^{2n + 1}) \\
&= -\ln(2) - x/2 - \sum \limits_{k = 1}^n\frac{B_{2k}}{2k}(4^k - 1) x^{2k} + O(x^{2n + 1})
\end{align*}$$

All together:
$$f(x) = x - \sum \limits_{k = 1}^n \frac{B_{2k}}{k} (4^k - 1)x^{2k} + O(x^{2k + 1}).$$

**Edit:** Since $|B_{2n}| \sim 4 \sqrt{\pi n} \left(\frac{n}{\pi e}\right)^{2n}$ the corresponding series has a convergence radius of $0$.

Answer (score 2):

I computed the various derivatives (thanks for the fun), computed the limits and obtained $$f(x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{6x^4}{4!}-\frac{360x^6}{6!}+\frac{85680x^8}{8!}-\frac{56246400x^{10}}{10!}+O(x^{11})$$ that is to say $$f(x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{x^6}{2}+\frac{17 x^8}{8}-\frac{31x^{10}}{2}+O\left(x^{11}\right)$$ hoping no mistake (and there were !).

Comment: Numerical calculations approve the terms upto $x^6$, but please check the $x^8$-term.

Comment: Sure about $85/4?$ If I substitute $y=1/x,\;$  compute the asymptotic expansion for $y\rightarrow \infty$ and backsubstitute I get a factor $17/8$

Comment: @gammatester This seems to be correct!

Comment: @gammatester Did you calculate the derivate numerically ?

Comment: @pPeter: No, using Maple 7 which refuses to compute the series for $x=0$ but computes the asymptotic expansion without problems.

Comment: @Peter. Thanks for pointing ! One extra $0$

Comment: @gammatester. Your idea is really good. The nightmare is gone !!

Comment: Here it is, not worth an answer and I am not sure if this approach is valid:
$$\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{2} (\frac{1}{y})^2 +\frac{1}{4}(\frac{1}{y})^4-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{y})^6$$
$$+\frac{17}{8}(\frac{1}{y})^8-\frac{31}{2}(\frac{1}{y})^{10}+\frac{691}{4}(\frac{1}{y})^{12}-\frac{5461}{2}(\frac{1}{y})^{14}$$
$$+\frac{929569}{16}(\frac{1}{y})^{16}-\frac{3202291}{2}(\frac{1}{y})^{18}$$

Comment: @gammatester. It is perfectly valid ! You had a great idea. It is even funny to see this problem. Thanks :-)